# Spring Validation - How to retrieve errors.rejectValue in my Contoller?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, spring-data

I have my validate method in my TestValidator as follows

```
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    Test test = (Test) target;
    String testTitle = test.getTestTitle();

    //**ErrorCheck1** - This works, and I am able to pull the value in my controller
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "testTitle", "test.testTitle.projec", "My msg");


    if (testTitle != null && testTitle.length() < 4) {
        logger.error("Inside custom validation"+test.testTitle().length());

        //**Error Check2**
        //***HOW DO I RETRIEVE THE BELOW VALUE in My controller
        errors.rejectValue(testTitle, "test.testTitle.lessThen4");
        errors.addAllErrors(errors);
        logger.error("Entered If condition of validate");
    }
}
```

And my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<BasicResponseDTO> newTest(@Valid  @RequestBody Test test, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()){
        logger.error("Entered Errors");
        BasicResponseDTO basicResponseDTO = new BasicResponseDTO();
        basicResponseDTO.setCode(ResponseCode.BAD_REQUEST);
        return new ResponseEntity<BasicResponseDTO>(basicResponseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

When my ErrorCheck1 condition is activated, my IF condition inside the controller is able to retrieve it.
However, in my ErrorCheck2, because of of the errors.rejectValue I immediately get an error on the console and am not able to gracefully handle the situation when the testTitle length is less than 4.

> What is the alternative to errors.rejectValue so that I may handle the
>   error in my controller ?

Comment: What are the ErrorCheck1 and ErrorCheck12?

Comment: Please see the commented part of code on lines 5 and 9. I have marked them in ** to make it clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok - Got it. All i had to do was change

> errors.rejectValue(testTitle, "test.testTitle.lessThen4");

to

> errors.reject(testTitle, "test.testTitle.lessThen4");

RejectValue is a Field error and is not global in nature.
Reject is a Global error and can be accessed from inside the errors list in the controller.

From the Documentation

> void reject(String errorCode, String defaultMessage);
>   Register a global error for the entire target object, using the given error description.

```
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
Test test = (Test) target;
String testTitle = test.getTestTitle();

//**ErrorCheck1** - This works, and I am able to pull the value in my controller
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "testTitle", "test.testTitle.projec", "My msg");


if (testTitle != null && testTitle.length() < 4) {
    logger.error("Inside custom validation"+test.testTitle().length());

    //**Error Check2**
    //***HOW DO I RETRIEVE THE BELOW VALUE in My controller
    errors.reject(testTitle, "test.testTitle.lessThen4");
    errors.addAllErrors(errors);
    logger.error("Entered If condition of validate");
   }
}
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access the value directly but there is a way to include the value into error message

```
${validatedValue}
```

If you annotate a field like this

```
@Size(min = 10, message =”Phone number entered [${validatedValue}] is invalid. It must have at least {min} digits”)
private String phoneNumber;
```

and enter `123` your error message should be

```
Phone number entered [123] is invalid. It must have at least 10 digits. Thus you can access the value.
```

See https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/07/26/including-field-value-in-validation-message-using-spring-validation-framework-for-jsr-303/

Comment: Since I am using a Rest, I want to capture the error event and send back an appropriate response to my front end. There must be a way, else I see the whole concept of Spring Validators for custom error message not powerful enough. Thanks.

Comment: If you store the value itself in the errors list you can interate result.errors and find the added one. And just return info from the error.

Comment: Yes. How does one store the value in the errors list without the annotations on the class as you described ? I thought of doing errors.addAllErrors(errors); but am not sure if that will work...

Comment: You in your code add the error to the list of all errors.

Comment: Sorry, lost you there. Can you probably edit the your answer pls. Thx.

Comment: In your controller set a break point and check errors list from the BindingResult.

Comment: Thanks for your time +1. I solved it as mentioned in my answer.